# How to let Windows 10 automatically add LAN route to my route table

Tags: windows, routing, lan, persistent

As you may know, if you connect your computer to LAN, you will alwasy automatically get a route like this:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     xxx.xxx.xx.1   xxx.xxx.xx.222     20
```

I accidentally deleted this route by this command (4 is my interface number for LAN):

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 if 4
```

Of course this is not cool, so added this route back (without persistent option -p):

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 xxx.xxx.xx.1 metric 20 if 4
```

Well this brings my problem, every time I restart my computer, I lose this route, but I do NOT want use persistent option (-p) because I believe there should be some automatic method to make LAN route table works, just as it used to.

So any ideas how could I fix this on Windows 10?

Comment: Are you sure the `-p` option is not the way it used to work ? What is wrong with it ?

Comment: `-p` works but it's not the default way (ugly), so I wanted a more elegant solution; but well, I just reinstalled Windows (for other reasons) and it's fine now :-D

Answer (score 1):

Remove your network and re-add it